# PostrgreSQL, Adding text from 2 columns with query

Tags: postgresql

I am filling data adapter directly with PostgreSQL query so I can't add strings when read through query results. But I need added text from two columns.

Say I have data:

> doc_id: 1,
>   doc_type: Bill,
>   doc_number: 145/2013
>   doc_price: 100.00

Those are 4 columns and I need 3 columns in result:

> 1 | Bill 145/2013 | 100.00

where doc_type and doc_number are strings and should be added like strings

> doc_type + 1 space + doc_number

Is this possible to do with SELECT query?
Something like this

```
SELECT doc_id, doc_type + " " + doc_number, doc_price FROM... WHERE...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure you can:

```
SELECT doc_id, doc_type || ' ' || doc_number as mynewFieldName, doc_price FROM... WHERE...
```

The string concatenation operator in PostgreSQL is `||` while the string delimiter is`'`